# Prove that the solution tends to $0$ as $t$ goes to infinity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to prove  that, if  $A(t)$ is a real symmetric $N\times N$ matrix whose
eigenvalues are all less than $-1$ for  all $t$, then if we consider $u$ to be the solution of
$$\dot u(t)=A(t)u(t),$$
Then 
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}|u(t)|^2=0.$$
The only thing I was able to do was to write down the solution, but  nothing more.. can you help
me? Many thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}|u(t)|^2=2\langle u(t),u'(t)\rangle=2\langle u(t),A(t)u(t)\rangle\leqslant-2\langle u(t),u(t)\rangle=-2|u(t)|^2,
$$
hence
$$
|u(t)|^2\leqslant|u(0)|^2\,\mathrm e^{-2t}.
$$

Comment: Where did you used that  the matrix is simmetric? Was it just a redundant information?

Comment: Why $\leqslant-1$ and not $\lt0$?

Comment: To ensure that $\langle v,Av\rangle\leqslant-\langle v,v\rangle$.

Comment: I don't know.. form your proof $<0$ seems to suffice indeed.. i copied the text as i found it..

Comment: I don't get your point about symmetry.. can you please provide more details?

Comment: Yes: real symmetric matrices are diagonalizable by orthogonal matrices hence $A(t)=P(t)^*D(t)P(t)$ with $P(t)$ orthogonal and $D(t)$ diagonal with diagonal entries the eigenvalues of $A(t)$. Thus, $\langle v,A(t)v\rangle=\langle w,D(t)w\rangle\leqslant-2|w|^2=-2|v|^2$ with $w=P(t)v$.

Comment: Excellent.. thank you did..